# What would be the best practice to achieve this particular formatting?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I am trying to replicate something like the page shown above. I was wondering what would be the best practices or standards regarding this?

Currently I'm using the smaller pics as lists and then wrapping them in span with `display: inline-block` styling so that the smaller pictures automatically stack next to the bigger picture. Also, for the text with the smaller pictures I'm styling the `<p>` with `inline-block` styling.

The whole thing seems to me like it's just working, like a hack. I am not using any css frameworks as I would like to do this task with custom css. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you using any frameworks like boostrap etc? They usually offer css classes from layouts to align content to specific columns and to take proportionate amounts of screen estate etc

Comment: No, am not. Bootstrap would really ease this whole thing but I'm sharpening my custom css skills.

Comment: Have you used css3 columns before? It's available in most modern browsers and may be the simplest way to define two columns http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_column-gap

Comment: Also I think yes inline block would be what you should use to have the content adjust in each sub div

Comment: what about li:first-child? so all will be in the same list and you just style the first one differently

Comment: I don't understand why you would see the application of html and css as "a hack".

Comment: @Dean219 have not but it looks good. I'll try it out.

Comment: @Can yeah, that's an interesting advice. Did not think of that

Comment: @CarolMcKay probably because it seems to me that I'm "somehow" making it work. It does not look standard. Just experiments and got it right.